# Structure for pin declarations

Tags: python, io, raspberry-pi, code-structure

I'm wondering how I should structure my code for the pin declarations of my MCP23017 (an I/O expander microchip) and whether I should put that in a function or not.

So currently I got the below script with my MCP's pin declarations and many functions using them. These functions are called by another file, and it's all this is on an Raspberry Pi.

```
import board
import busio
from digitalio import Direction
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017
import time


i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp0 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x27)
pin00 = mcp0.get_pin(0)
pin00.direction = Direction.OUTPUT
pin01 = mcp0.get_pin(1)
pin01.direction = Direction.OUTPUT
etc

pins = (pin00, pin01, etc)


def relays_off():
    i = 0
    while i < len(pins):
        if not pins[i].value:
            pins[i].value = True
        i += 1

def other_function():
    etc
```

The whole project is about controlling relays, controlled by those pins.
The issue is that every time I power it up I get an error and the relays are randomly activated/deactivated. The error is `[Errno 121] Remote I/O error`.
I have to execute a bunch of `relays_off()` to calm it down until I get no more errors, then it works fine.

So I'm first wondering if I coded that correctly, or if the pin declaration should be in a function called by the other functions?

Comment: Just to clarify, if a pin's value is True, does that mean it's OFF? I know nothing about RP development but that sounds unusual. One might normally expect True == ON and False == OFF

Comment: I think an excellent way to approach this situation would be to define a `MCP23017` class that encapsulated the chip's characteristics and provided whatever methods were needed to control it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes for my relay boards if it's on their is no contact.

Answer (score 0):

Imports omitted for brevity...

How about having all the pins in a list? e.g.,

```
NPINS = 5 # or whatever

def initpin(mcp, n):
    pin = mcp.get_pin(n)
    pin.direction = Direction.OUTPUT
    pin.value = True
    return pin

mcp0 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x27)
    
pinlist = [initpin(mcp0, i) for i in range(NPINS)]
```

Subsequently you could access the pins by their respective index in pinlist.

Not sure if that helps